# Show video in AVPlayer with full screen when mobile is turned to landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation

I have created an video player using `AVPlayer` in my project. I have created options to play, pause and forward the video playing. I am facing an issue now, to display the videoplayer in `landscape`**(FULL SCREEN)**, when user rotates it. My app works on portrait only.

Please give me any suggestion to make my video player to show videos on landscape with full screen.

Please find my code below that i used to create `avPlayer`

```
// self.avPlayer is @property(nonatomin,strong)AvPlayer avPlayer;

        self.avPlayer= [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
        layerr = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
        AVPlayerItem *currentItem = self.avPlayer.currentItem;
        currentTime = currentItem.cu`enter code here`rrentTime; //playing time
        CMTime duration = self.avPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration;
        float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
        self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        layerr.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer: layerr];


        [self.avPlayer play];
        [self.view addSubview:self.btnPause];
```

Comment: are you add landscape in supportedInterfaceOrientations ?

Comment: Please check the answer explained how to set Supported interface orientations

Comment: My app should work only in portrait. For video player alone the screen should turn landscape. Please helme for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Supported interface orientations** from `info.plist` add key “Supportedinterfaceorientations”  or you can set it from as below steps and screen shot attached.

1) Select xCodeProject and Project Navigator

2) Select Traget > General

3) Under Deployment Info Select device orientation which you want to support.

For other view which you don't want to support all orientation. Add below Method :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}
```

Hope this will help you to set orientation.

Do let me know if you require any other information.

Comment: My app should work only in portrait. For video player alone the screen should turn landscape. Please helme for that.

Comment: @ragulml event you want to support all other view in Portrait only. you need to set Supported interface orientations. and in view controller you need to set  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
} ........ I have done this too. No results :)

Comment: can you brief step by step what you Implemented ?

Comment: i have set interface orientation to portrait. And for AutoRotate i have given "NO" . And for Supported interface orientation i have given landscape